# Communicate between two different application using signalR

Tags: signalr

I have two web application using signalR. Both application have its on Hub to look after client request.

Site Name: xyz:81 (hosted on port 81 in iis).
signalR HubName: MyDashboardHub

Site Name: abc:8100 (hosted on port 8100 in iis)
signalR Hub Name: MyWorkflowHub

Both application using window authentication.
I have tried following code to call xyz:81 hub's function from application abc:8100, but getting 'Unauthorized' exception

**Code on xyz application**

```
public class MyDashboardHub : Hub
{
    public void ReloadWIP(string memberCode)
    {
        Clients.OthersInGroup(memberCode).reloadWIP();
    }
}
```

**Code on abc application from default.aspx.cs**

```
var hubConn = new Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.HubConnection("http://localhost:81/signalr/", false);

            var name = "MyDashboardHub";
            var hubProxy = hubConn.CreateHubProxy(name);
            hubConn.Start().Wait();
            hubProxy.Invoke("ReloadWIP", "7048");
```

**Exception**:

```
StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
 Cache-Control: private
 Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
 WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
 WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
 Date: Wed, 22 Apr 2015 00:17:35 GMT
 Content-Length: 6449
 Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
}
```

I am new in signalR. I am still don't know that can i talk between two different application using signalR? if i can than what is wrong in code or configuration?

Answer (score 1):

I found work around. Need to add credential.

```
connection.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```